# How can i use same header and footer in every reportviewer?

Tags: asp.net, header, footer, reportviewer

I am developing an ASP.NET application and i need to create a lot of report with same header and footer "skeleton". There is a way to create a custom component to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to make one Report with coresponding header/footer and then use it a s template. I have few of those. When I need new report, I just open Template and then use "Save As" and name it as I like.

Comment: But if you change the template, you need to change all reports?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :) In theory (haven't tried that), you could make Subreport and put it in your Header, then you will need to remake only your subreport. I don't like this approach because subreports slows down render a bit.